# How to inject dataSource default bean in Spring Boot integration test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot automatically creates dataSource bean when you specify configuration of dataSource in application.properties (spring.datasource prefix). So I don't have explicit dataSource bean configuration.

Now I need to create integration test for partial Spring Configuration. This spring configuration autowires dataSource bean. How can I create default Spring Boot dataSource bean for integration testing of partial spring configuration? Is it possible with `@ContextConfiguration` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tipically do this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class ApplicationTests {
```

if I want to test my `@Configuration` class using Boot infrastructure.

When `Application` is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I would like to load as less as possible during my integration test. You have insights into Spring guts. Is my approach somehow incorrect?

Comment: Also I mentioned that I want to test partial configuration. Is it a good idea to use @EnableAutoConfiguration with partial configuration? Partial = configuration for particular module.

Comment: I'm not sure that for `partial configuration` the Boot AutoConfig stuff has a place...

Comment: I deleted my answer, because you are right. @EnableAutoConfiguration is needed to create default dataSource. I missed that I included it into my configuration class, when I was trying to resolve the problem.